# xor 2 binary strings and give result in binary using java

Tags: java

I have two very large binary strings as below.
How do I perform a bitwise xor on these big strings and display result in binary?

string 1.
`100011010011000000001011101100101110111111101110101111101000111110110100011000010100010000101010111101000100011111101001110010010011111100110110100010000000011000101000011010100000110100001011001111000001100100101110111101111001010100100010110001001010110000011111011111010001001011101001110001100100011101100101100000011011101111010000001000000111111111110111100101101011010100011010100101000001101001110110011111011111110101010000111011111011011011100111001000011000011011111100101001110001111110001000000101000100110010111011011010100100111000001010110000101111000010110001011100010010110100010111111001000110011100111100111010100111110001110010110111010000010101000111110110110101010101000111110100010010000000110010000010101100101100101100100100110011000101101100000010100010101010011101101110101101111011010010101011001001000001011100011010101100111100110110101101101110000011010101101111`

string 2. `110001010111000100111011101010101010001011010111111000101010101111100100010111010000010100010110111111010000111110000101111000010010111000111110100000000011011100011100011101100010000101101010000000010011100101111011101001111110100100000010110001011000110100100111000001010001101111101101110111100011001101111100101101001110101111111100000010000111011111111111110101101101000000001110110101000100001101000011010000010001010101010001101000101011101011100110000110001000101011000100110111110110101110100001010111010101010011110011001101100010001000001110100111101111000011011101010010000011100000011011100101000101011101001000101100100101010100111010111010010100000010010110111000110011000101011111101110010110010100000110001100111001111101110001101011110001000001010101010110101111011011001101101011101111001010001111101000011101110100001100000001111110111100101010100011101110000011101100100010000010000000100101010110000010011000011110000001010111110110010100101000011001110110010001110000001111011110000011110011110101010010010001000000000010100001100110110001010110010110000100001011000100011110111100111110`

Comment: The length should be the same, but it is obviously not the same. Basically, you have to do it digit by digit.

Comment: undownvoted as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325781/xor-2-binary-strings-and-give-result-in-binary-using-java/17325829?noredirect=1#comment25132097_17325829

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use BigInteger:

[`BigInteger(String val, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

[`BigInteger.XOR(BigInteger val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#xor%28java.math.BigInteger%29)

[`BigInteger.toString(int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29)

Comment: +1 this is the simplest solution. It is guaranteed to produce correct results and it's using a built in which means it's better tested. Also, I liked how like in my answer you provided OP with helpful hints rather than code.

Comment: thank you Ziyao. Actually I know the iteration and bitwise operation. I was searching for some builtin functions. Thankyou

Comment: @yaswanthchilukuri you should mention all the options you have already dismissed in the question. If you show your research by saying "I have already done this, but I feel there must be an easier solution: ...", people are much more likely to help you.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I will do that when i ask a question next time. Thanks for the suggession.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds to me like homework or an assignment, so I'll offer guidance rather than code:

- Create an empty [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
- Iterate through these strings using a [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) with an index `i`
- Use [`charAt(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) to grab the character at position `i`
- If both characters are the equivalent at that position, [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%29) `0` to the string builder, otherwise append `1` to it
- When you're done iterating, [return that string builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: perfect hints for a homework. I like people who gives this kind of answer to homework instead of providing direct codes. +1

Comment: @aaronman You'll need a string builder for output anyways, so you can just skip the middleman. You don't have to, however.

Comment: @aaronman OP is using strings, conversion to a BitSet and using [xor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#xor(java.util.BitSet) and then converting back would also be a viable solution - although I do not know of a simple way to convert a bit string to a bit set.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum if the bitset implementation is decent shouldn't xoring be faster since you can do mutiple entries at a time not to mention no branches, though I agree if you were forced to start with a string it might be a pain to convert it to a bitset

Comment: @aaronman In order to convert the string to a bitset you'd have to do what the simple algorithm I suggested does anyway (iterate through both strings).

Comment: But no branches in my solution, or the big int for that matter

Comment: @aaronman you need some branching to populate the array lists and then to present them to the user

Comment: @JanDvorak i think you could avoid the branching if you were clever

Answer (score 0):

IMO the most fitting solution is to use java's [bitset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) since that is essentially what you have. bitsets have all the standard bit manipulation operations, like a normal int, but they can be as large as you want. Converting a string to a bitset may be annoying (probably just loop through each character) but after that the rest is easy just use instance method `xor()` and then `toString()` to print it